# How do I hide the HUD in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to hide the HUD in Diablo 3, in order to make better screenshots. Is it possible to hide it temporarily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is not yet a way to hide the HUD in Diablo III.

Comment: There is (may have been added in an update): https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/312427/148510

Answer (score 2):

By default you can toggle UI using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image]

The mouse cursor isn't hidden and can't be fully moved away from the screen.